# itertools over multiple variables into one

Tags: python, python-itertools

I am trying to put multiple variables into one tuple however am struggling a bit with the itertools. I would appreciate if someone could kindly assist, here is the current code:

```
    rotors = (
                 Rotor(wiring='LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS', alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', notch='', setting='A', ring_offset=23),  # Beta
                 Rotor(wiring='EKMFLGDQVZNTOWYHXUSPAIBRCJ', alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', notch='Q', setting='A', ring_offset=2),  # Rotor 1
                 Rotor(wiring='BDFHJLCPRTXVZNYEIWGAKMUSQO', alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ', notch='V', setting='A', ring_offset=10),  # Rotor 3
             )[::-1]

    reflector = Reflector(wiring='YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT', alphabet='ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'),  # reflector B

    rotors_options = [rotors for i in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=len(rotors)-1)]
```

My objective is to have the rotors_options also including the reflector option, currently I only have the router_options in the tuple:

[image]

Here is the code I tried:

```
rotors_options = [rotors for i in itertools.product(string.ascii_uppercase, repeat=len(rotors)-1)]
```

The code unfortunately does not include the `reflector` in the iterations, how do I add this?

I would like to have an output that has the Rotor with the static 'reflector' for every iteration:
[image]

adding the reflectors to the tuple:
[image]

Any assistance to get it included in the iterations will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to put `reflector` and `rotors` at the same level in `rotors_options`, or do you want to somewhat match each `rotor` with the corresponding `reflector`?

Comment: I would like to have the reflector corresponding to the rotor and repeat this for multiple times `len(rotors)-1)`

Answer (score 0):

[`itertools.product`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

```
import itertools

rotors = (
    Rotor(
        wiring="LEYJVCNIXWPBQMDRTAKZGFUHOS",
        alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ",
        notch="",
        setting="A",
        ring_offset=23,
    ),  # Beta
    ...
)[::-1]

reflector = (
    Reflector(
        wiring="YRUHQSLDPXNGOKMIEBFZCWVJAT", alphabet="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    ),
)  # reflector B

rotors_options = [
    i for i in itertools.product(rotors, reflector) if i[0].alphabet == i[1].alphabet
]
```

This may achieve what you want to do. It places rotors and reflectors that have the same `alphabet` attribute (or anything else you want) in the same tuple:

```
[(Rotor(...), Reflector(...)), ...]
```

Note that rotors that don't have a matching reflector will be omitted, and having an empty tuple of reflectors will result in an empty `rotors_options`.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback. I tried the proposed code, however I am not able to get any response from this: `rotors_options = [i for i in itertools.product(rotors, reflector) if i[0].alphabet == i[1].alphabet]` my output is empty

Comment: I'm assuming that the `alphabet` attribute can be access via `i[n].alphabet`, it's possible that it's not the right way for your `Rotor` class. What happens if you remove `if i[0].alphabet == i[1].alphabet`?

Comment: PS, perhaps you need to just copy the last few lines and run the data setup part with your own code.

Comment: If I run the code without the 'if i[0].alphabet == i[1].alphabet' I get the output without the reflector however only 3 outputs, not repeated for every combination as I did with `repeat=len(rotors)-1`.

Comment: I updated the question with an image of the output. So I would like to get the `rotor_options` -- `000` -- `0` then Rotor and reflector for every instance like 000 -- 0, 000 -- 1, 000 -- 2 then 001 -- 0, 001 -- 1, etc.